# OpenCV grabcut: how to combine GC_INIT_WITH_RECT and GC_INIT_WITH_MASK

Tags: c++, opencv

I couldn't find an example of this in C++, so if someone could show me that'd be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not explicitly stated in the documentation, the `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` and `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` flags are mutually exclusive. If you pass both to `grabCut()`, `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT` will be preferred, and the other ignored.

To prove this, here is the relevant snippet from OpenCV's source code:

```
if( mode == GC_INIT_WITH_RECT )
    initMaskWithRect( mask, img.size(), rect );
else // flag == GC_INIT_WITH_MASK
    checkMask( img, mask );
```

Comment: Actually, what is confusing is that the doc does say explicitly they can be combined: "Note that GC_INIT_WITH_RECT and GC_INIT_WITH_MASK can be combined."  However, they can't, would it be simply for the fact that GC_INIT_WITH_RECT = 0, so there is no way of telling whether GC_INIT_WITH_MASK has been ORed with GC_INIT_WITH_RECT or not. Defining everything outside the rectangle as GC_BGD in the mask is the only way to "combine" the two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Aurelius answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24641003/5008845)

---

When you use the `GC_INIT_WTH_RECT` mode what the `grabCut()` function does is it sets everything outside of the rectangle to `GC_BGD`, and everything in the rectangle as `GC_PR_FGD`. So using this mode initializes the mask for you.

If you want to use a rectangle **and** mark your own sure-foreground/background, then use the mode `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK`.

Create your own mask, an array of zeros, same size as the `img` input into `grabCut()`. Set everything within the rectangle to `GC_PR_FGD`. Everything outside should be `GC_BGD`. Then if you know a pixel is sure-foreground, set it to `GC_FGD`, and if you know something is probably background set it to  `GC_PR_BGD`.

`GC_` values correspond to:

```
GC_BGD     0
GC_FGD     1
GC_PR_BGD  2
GC_PR_FGD  3
```

This is what I did when I wanted to use a rectangle as well as normal user input.

Comment: I edited a few things. It's better to use the names instead of the literal value. Nice answer :D